# Dynamic Jquery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

How do I default an accordion to be closed on start-up. here is the sample view [here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion-custom.htm)

Here is the code:

```
<script>
$(function() { 

$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h3', effect: 'slide'});
});
</script>

<script>

// add new effect to the tabs
$.tools.tabs.addEffect("slide", function(i, done) {

    // 1. upon hiding, the active pane has a ruby background color
    this.getPanes().slideUp("slow").css({backgroundColor: "#fff"});

    // 2. after a pane is revealed, its background is set to its original color (transparent)
    this.getPanes().eq(i).slideDown("slow", function()  {
        $(this).css({backgroundColor: 'transparent'});

        // the supplied callback must be called after the effect has finished its job
        done.call();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just an an aside here, there is a jQuery UI Accordion which is `.accordion()` http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ May want to clarify you're actually using the tabs widget in the question :)

Comment: I am not using the widget I have re-posted with the link of the sample that I am following

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$("#accordion")
  .tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h3', effect: 'slide', collapsible: true})
  .tabs('select', false);
```

This marks it as `collapsible`, then selects a tab that's not there to display, using `false`.

Comment: doesn't work

$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h3', accordion: true})
.tabs('select', false);
;
});

Comment: doesn't work

$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h3', effect: 'slide', accordion: true})
.tabs('select', false);
;
});

Comment: @kwek-kwek you're missing the collapsible: true in the options on both of those :) scroll right in my answer to see what I mean

Comment: Ok my bad heheh here is that I have now <script>
$(function() { 

$("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div.pane", {tabs: 'h3', effect: 'slide', collapsible: true})
.tabs('select', false);
;
});
</script> still not working

Answer (score 0):

put in your css:

```
#accordion div.pane: display:none;
```